# Django: Cross referencing Model objects within a model - best practise?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-1.11

I'm currently going around in a bit of a `"QuerySet' object has no attribute ''` <> `app.models.DoesNotExist: Messages matching query does not exist` loop.

Essentially, I'm trying to define "last_activity" on a Room model that is referencing the time at which the last Message associated to that room was sent. This is my attempt:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, default='')
    banner = models.ImageField(storage=USER_UPLOAD_LOC, null=True, blank=True)

    def last_activity(self):
       last_persisted_message = Messages.objects.filter(where=self.title).order_by('-sent_at')[:1]
       return last_persisted_message.sent_at


class Messages(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    where = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = models.TextField(default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    username_from = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username_to = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='all')
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

I've tried so many things now and referenced the query set documentation and nothing seems to be working.

I can also confirm that the "where" field for the Messages model is populated when a message is created by {{ room.title }}. I'm using a web socket connection on the client side to pass a "message" back to the websocket consumer.py which then persists the message to the DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *slice* the queryset with `[:1]` you will obtain a queryset containing *at most one item*, but not an item itself. You can use `[0]` to obtain the first item, or, `.first()`:

```
def last_activity(self):
    last_persisted_message = Messages.objects \
                                     .filter(where=self.slug) \
                                     .order_by('-sent_at') \
                                     .first()
    if last_persisted_message is not None:
        return last_persisted_message.sent_at
```

If you use `[0]` and there is no such item, then the program will raise an `IndexError` (since there is no item with index 0).

In case there is no such `Messages` object (that satisfies the `filter(..)`), then `last_persisted_message` will be `None`, so you have to find a way to resolve that case. Here we return `None` in that case.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer because I think I had it right - I just need where=self.slug (where was the slug field and not the title!) Darn it. Thank you for the prompts tho.